# llvm error: Found more than one landing-pad successor

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, exception, llvm, intermediate-language

llvm has a `MachineVerifier` pass which checks a `MachineFunction` for correctness based on different parameters like: *liveness*, *dead Basic Block*, *correct register class* etc. Recently I came across this error from the MachineVerifier pass. 
I'm wondering why is it not okay to have multiple landing pad successors?
In the example I am getting this error the layout (IR) is like this;

```
BB0: 
...
succ: BB1


BB1: EH_LANDING_PAD
pred: BB0, BB1
...
succ: BB1, BB2


BB2: EH_LANDING_PAD
...

 Bad machine code: MBB has more than one landing pad successor ***
   - function:    _Z7ex_testv
   - basic block: BB#1 lpad (0x1bf7c90)
   LLVM ERROR: Found 1 machine code errors.
```

Does it mean that if an exception occurs, exception handling will be ambiguous. Can someone please explain. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Multiple landing pads are prohibited. landing pad is where the exception is landed by the unwinder. Strictly speaking, there is no problem of handling the landing pads with non-intersecting typeinfo's, but when you have e.g. cleanup or filter you might end in the trouble...